# Assign figure to correct subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have a set of `subplot's` that display different information. For the example below, I can assign the scatter plot to the designated subplot but the two `distplot` occupy the last subplot created.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = [1,4,5,6,7,8]
x2 = [3,4,8,2,8,8]
y = [1,2,4,8,1,9]

def L_plot(ax, fontsize=12):
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_title('L', fontsize=10) 
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.scatter(x, y)

def E_plot(ax2,pid, fontsize=12):
    ax2.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=8)
    ax2.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=8)
    ax2.set_title('E', fontsize=10)
    ax2.grid(False)
    ax2 = sns.distplot(x, kde=False, norm_hist=True, color='b', bins = 10)

def D_plot(ax,pid, fontsize=12):
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_title('D', fontsize=10)
    ax.grid(False)
    ax = sns.distplot(x2, kde=False, norm_hist=True, color='b', bins = 10)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (0, 0))  
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (1, 0))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (2, 0))

L_plot(ax1,1)
E_plot(ax2,1)
D_plot(ax3,1)
```

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

I'm trying to assign `E_plot` to  the `subplot` in the second row but both `distplot's` are located in the last `subplot` created.

I'm not sure if the seaboard packages can't be assigned or I'm not correctly assigning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call signature for [`distplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) is:

```
seaborn.distplot(a, bins=None, hist=True, kde=True, rug=False,
                 fit=None, hist_kws=None, kde_kws=None, rug_kws=None, 
                 fit_kws=None, color=None, vertical=False,
                 norm_hist=False, axlabel=None, label=None,
                 ax=None)
```

Notice the last option. If you don't tell it which Axes object to use, it'll use the one returned by `pyplot.gca()` (gca = "get current Axes").

So you need to do, e.g.,

```
sns.distplot(x2, kde=False, norm_hist=True, color='b', bins=10, ax=ax2)
```